# create a class for each user name with varrying variables

Tags: java

Here's what I'm trying to do:

-add user profiles based on a blueprint(class)

-using a "next empty slot in a array" finder to set a variable to that next empty slot number

-and using that next empty slot number as a user profile number to create a user profile so I can reference that profile from other parts of the program using the slot/user number

```
public user[] userNum= new user[99];

public void createNewUser(){
    int nextUserNum = 99;
    for(int i = 0; i < userNum.length; i++){
        if (userNum[i] == null){
            nextUserNum = i;
            break;
        }
    user <nextUserNum> = new user(nextUserNum); //ERROR AREA
    }
}
```

-this ERROR AREA point, between the "< >", is where I'd like the variable for the user class to be the number generated by the code above it

-this way every time I initiate creatNewUser(); its creates a new user(); class with the nextUserNum assigned as its user number to identify it later

-so when I choose to edit a user profile and ask which user profile I'm editing I can enter in this "user number' and it will only change the "userName" in the user profile I entered

```
int userToEdit;
    System.out.println("What is the User Number for the User you wish to Edit:");
    userToEdit = keyboard.nextInt();

String first, middle, last;
        System.out.println("First Name:");
        first = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Middle Name:");
        middle = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Last Name:");
        last = keyboard.nextLine();

        <userToEdit>.changeUserName(first, middle, last); //ERROR AREA
```

-this ERROR AREA, betweeen the "< >", is where I believe my change needs to be made, I need a way for User Number answer to the question about to be the variable in the changeUserName(); method

-honestly not sure if I can even perform this in this way, but cannot find a specific solution to the task I'm trying to perform in my textbook. pleaseHelp();

Comment: are you meaning `userNum [nextUserNum] = new user (nextUserNum);`  ???

Comment: Are you meaning creating an *object* for each new username? Really your question is far from clear.

Comment: Don't you just need to append the `user` object to the list of users?

Comment: Java does not have "dynamic" variable names, but more importantly, you don't need them.

Comment: yes I'm meaning `userNum [nextUserNum] = new user (nextUserNum);`     and creating an object for each userNumber, but yes I think your saying the same thing, sorry it's so unclear, I'm very very new at this